# Create function in Excel using Trapezoidal Rule in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, integral

I am trying to create a VBA code in Excel to run integral function using Trapezoidal Rule. When I enter "INTEG("x^2+3*x+ln(x)",1,9)" in Excel formula it gives me an error. Could you please suggest how I could improve my code (see below). Thank you so much!

```
Function INTEG(exp As String, min As Double, max As Double)
Dim t As Double
Dim x As Integer
Dim range As Double
Dim exparray(5000) As Double
Dim dx As Double

range = max - min
dx = range / 5000
t = min
x = 0

Do Until x = 5000
exparray(x) = Evaluate(Replace(exp, "x", CStr(t))) * dx + 0.5 * dx * Abs(Evaluate(Replace(exp, "x", CStr(t + dx))) - Evaluate(Replace(exp, "x", CStr(t))))
t = t + dx
x = x + 1
Loop

INTEG = WorksheetFunction.sum(exparray)
End Function
```

Comment: With your example, is the correct output `374.441691086355`? I can run this in my Excel without any errors.  What error are you getting?

Comment: hello @BruceWayne thanks a lot for your answer! Not sure, to be honest. Could you please specify which settings section you are asking about, I can upload a screenshot. Would appreciate your advice.